# Ajax.ActionLink not working MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

I have a grid, I need to add Details column to the grid and when the detail column is selected the details for that row should appear just below the current grid.

My Code :

```
<% Html.Grid(Model.InnerModel.StatusRecords)
        .Empty("No data available")
        .Attributes(new Hash(id => "resultsTable"))
        .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.For(x => Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "BatchDetailsByStatus", "ReportsController", new { statusId = x.Status, jobNo = Model.InnerModel.JobNumber }, new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET", 
                UpdateTargetId = "StatusBatchDetailsDiv"})).Named("Details").DoNotEncode();  
            column.For(x => x.Status);
            column.For(x => x.TotalCount).Named("Count");
         }).Render(); %>
```

My Controller code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
     public ActionResult BatchDetailsByStatus(int statusId, string jobNo)
     {
         var batchModel = BatchByStatus.GetBatchDetailsByStatus(statusId, jobNo);
         return PartialView("BatchDetailsByStatus", batchModel);
     }
```

I have a partailview BatchDetailsByStatus that gets all the required data to display.

But when I click on the Details link nothing happens, it does not work.

What am I missing out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced ReportsController with Reports (controller name without Controller) in Ajax.ActionLink, and it worked

Comment: Yes, because the routing engine automatically adds "Controller" to the end of your routing string, as part of its "Configuration by Convention."  I found this a bit counter-intuitive as well, at first.